# HTML5 date field and placeholder text in Safari

Tags: ipad, html, safari, mobile-safari

I've got an issue, but I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong, or if this feature just isn't supported yet.

Basically I have the following lines of code:

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last name" />

<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" value="" placeholder="Date of birth" />
```

I've tested this on the desktop version of Safari and all good, but when I test it on the iPad, the second input doesn't show the placeholder text.  Does anyone know if placeholder text is supported on type="date" on the iPad?

Cheers
Nick

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The iPad is doing the correct thing.  The `placeholder` attribute [isn't supported on `input` elements on type `date`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary).  It's probably working on desktop Safari because that doesn't support the `date` type, so that attribute is being ignored and you're left with a plain text field.  You could check in the DOM inspector.

Comment: Cheers.  Thanks for the link to a great resource too!  Bookmarked for later use.  Must say this feels a little strange that you are able to have placeholder text on some text fields, but not others.  What if I wanted to add the format as a placeholder for instance - 'dd/mm/yy'?

Comment: But that's the point, a date input isn't supposed to be a text field.

Comment: Semantics.  It's an input field then, that on an iPad rather than brings up the normal keyboard on focus brings up a datepicker selection.

Comment: Of course it's semantics.  That's the whole point of having different types of `input` in the first place.  The format for a correctly implemented `date` input is *always* yyyy-mm-dd.  You're not supposed to be able to free type it, you're supposed to pick it from a control.

Comment: but what if you're using the placeholder as a label, which is the case with some mobile layouts? then it becomes an annoyance.

Comment: Your scenario is not really a proper use of the placeholder field - that's what labels and legends and such are for.  Ultimately I agree with you that the browser should be responsible for clearly marking the field as a date input and providing a way for designers to customize it.  In the meantime if you just want something to show up by default in the field you can set the value attribute to a date formatted like "YYYY-MM-DD", it will at least render with a pre-populated value but one caveat - if this is a required field your users may not feel compelled to manually change it.

Comment: I wish I could get the placeholder to say "Alarm will ring on 12/31/2013" instead of simply "Dec 31, 2013", which requires a label to be placed outside of the input field.

Answer (score 7):

Slight hack bit here goes...

Initially have the field as a text field. When the user focuses on the field switch the fields type to date and re-focus.

tested in ios6

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="DOB" id="dob" />
```

**JS**

```
<script>

    var textbox = document.getElementById('dob')
        textbox.onfocus = function (event) {
            this.type = 'date';
            this.focus();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS for iOS Safari:

```
input[type='date']:after {
  color: #aaa;
  content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

Then use placeholder on date input:

```
<input name="mydate" type="date" value="" placeholder="Select a date" />
```

Comment: While this does work, the placeholder remains even after selecting a value (at least it does for `time` types)

Comment: @sMyles I solved this doing `input[type='date']:empty:after {...`

Comment: `:empty`doesn't seem to work as of 2023 on Safari so I went for `invalid:` (if input is required).

Answer (score 3):

Using the solution of sidarcy:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" value="" 
   placeholder="Date of birth"  
   onfocus="this.type='date';this.focus();" 
   onblur="if(this.value == '') this.type='text';"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

add this to header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var datefield = document.createElement("input")
    datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
    if (datefield.type != "date") { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
        document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
        document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n')
    }
    if (datefield.type != "date") { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        jQuery(function($) { //on document.ready
            $('input[type="date"]').datepicker();
            $('input[type="date"]').attr('placeholder', 'dd.mm.rrrr');
        });
    }
</script>
```