# "input type=date" placeholder on iOS?

Tags: iphone, html, placeholder

I'm currently developing a website aimed at iPhones/ iPads.

Setting the input type to date changes the field appearance to a drop down menu, and the placeholder attribute that works with text fields only shows on the desktop version, not on the iphone. Is there a way around this?

This is how it currently looks; http://i44.tinypic.com/2u91xsz.png

I want to get rid of that closing date text and have something similar to the dropdown menu above it.

Its basically just so that I can let the user know what they are entering without the need to use any extra space on the screen, so its not the biggest issue if there is no solution.

Comment: See my answer here, it works for me on iOS 9.3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39030299/2293304

Answer (score 5):

Took me a while figuring this one out, leave it as type="text", and add onfocus="(this.type='date')"

i even like the onblur i've seen mentioned

```
<input placeholder="Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
```

Comment: This seems to work mostly ok, however on iOS 9.x when I first tap the input, it gets stuck somewhere between a text input state and the date input state.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this is that it requires two taps. One to change it to date, one to actually get the datepicker open.

Comment: This was my solution as well. Unfortunately it doesn't work on iOS, as I'm having the same issue as @CraigPresti-MSFT. Did anybody get a solution after all these years?

Answer (score 2):

> the placeholder attribute that works with text fields only shows on
>   the desktop version, not on the iphone. Is there a way around this?

Try using javascript and css.

```
<div id="closing_date">
<label for="closing_date_field" class="overlabel">Closing Date</label>
<input id="closing_date_field" type="date" name="closing_date">
</div>
```

see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xK5S3/)

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain it the best. It needs to remain as input type=date. This is what it currently looks like: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v605/MANU80/e24e70b5.jpg , I want to get rid of that closing date text and have something similar to the dropdown menu above it.

Comment: Updated the input type to date. That essentially add a "placeholder" using javascript to the input.

Comment: I'm afraid its still not working, the placeholder attribute works on desktop but I dont think it applies to safari, its still showing up as a blank dropdown menu.

Comment: Has any progress been made on this? Thanks

Comment: @Kai sorry, missed your statements previously. See the updated answer. I've tested that jsfiddle link using html5 supported browser which at this time, it is opera (version 11.61 build 1250). The "Closing Date" label appear on the input date field itself and if a date is selected from the drop down calendar, the value is now display.

Comment: Credit should be given to this [author](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/makingcompactformsmoreaccessible/)

Comment: Are there any errors in this code? Adding it below my js which is loaded on document ready causes all my js to stop working. thanks $("document").ready( function (){ });

Comment: I don't think there is any error in the code as I've provide the code to jsfiddle in the answer? Your question is entirely another question and you will want to create another question for that.

Comment: Hi @Jasonw, it is possible to hide placeholder default of input "type=date" in mobile screen (responsive test mode) on desktop version?

Comment: Really, I don't know keyword to research it, because the type date not allow text, the default format (mm/dd/yy) impossible to hidden :(. Sorry for my knowledge.

You can see desktop version: http://i.imgur.com/w96j8h3.jpg

The responsive version test with Google Chrome responsive tool: http://i.imgur.com/nofjM3a.jpg

Actually, your solution work good on iphone, but I don't know how to hide the default value of date and time on desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I've made it work with some ":before" pseudo-class and a small bit of javascript.
You will have to have a class or id on your input. Here is a sample with an id of "myInput"

```
 #myInput:before{ content:"Date of birth"; width:100%; color:#AAA; } 
 #myInput:focus:before,
 #myInput.not_empty:before{ content:none }
```

Then in javascript, add the "not_empty" class depending on the value in the onChange and onKeyUp events.

You can even add all of this dynamically on every date fields.

Here is a rough code to do this :

```
$('input[type=date]').each(function(){
    var input=$(this);
    var id=input.attr('id');
    if (!id){
        id='RandomGeneratedId_'+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        input.attr('id',id);
    }
    var placeholder=input.attr('placeholder');
    if (placeholder){
        $('head').append('<style> #'+id+':before{ content:"'+placeholder+'"; width:100%; color:#AAA; } #'+id+':focus:before,#'+id+'.not_empty:before{ content:none }</style>');
    }
    input.on('change keyup',function(){
        if ($(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('not_empty')
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('not_empty')
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

It's not perfect but it's working well in Chrome and iOS7 webviews

Comment: You could use: `content:attr(placeholder);` To allow the HTML to set the content.

Comment: great idea! will give it a try and update my answer, thanks. This should allow to clean up a little the JS code

Comment: We now use this code into our Cobalt hybrid framework (http://cobaltians.org) where we developed a native datePicker component to ease the use of inputs like this. This framework can also help you with native transition between pages and native action bars