# Input type="date" placeholder - mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Hi what is the best work around for having placeholder text on a input with type="date"?

I want the phone to use it's own functionality for date selection on a site, rather than keypad input, but iOS devices ignore any date placeholder.

Have a tried a JS work around, but just crashed any androids viewing it.

Comment: Could this help in any way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622420/input-type-date-placeholder-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) could help you here. They have many widgets that are supposed to work on a wide range of devices, such as Android or iOS. Their text widget supports date picking, and a fully featured demo of this widget can be found [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/textinputs/#Date).