# How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?

Tags: html

It's impossible to use placeholder on date fields but I really need it.

I want two date inputs with texts "From" and "To" on each one as placeholders.

Comment: Set ad efault value that disappears `onfocus` and reappears `onblur` ?

Comment: When you simulate placeholder behavior in incompatible browsers, be mindful of how that will affect your validation.

Comment: From and To are `<label>`s, not `placeholder`s.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I'm using the following CSS only trick:

```css
  input[type="date"]:before {
    content: attr(placeholder) !important;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
  }
  input[type="date"]:focus:before,
  input[type="date"]:valid:before {
    content: "";
  }
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="Choose a Date" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to show up as "placeholdermm/dd/yyyy" in Chrome.

Comment: Yep. Works only on iOS and Chrome on Android. It's a hack :)

Comment: Add `margin-right: 0.5em;` to the first declaration, to create a nice separation between the placeholder and the input. You can also change the first line to: `content: attr(placeholder)':';`, to add a colon between the placeholder and input.

Comment: You would only have to add `!important` after the :focus and :valid content attribute because otherwise it gets overriden. Otherwise, nice hack :)

Comment: On iOS 9 you don't even need the `input[type="date"]:focus:before, input[type="date"]:valid:before` part.

Comment: Works on chrome now.

Comment: I will also say that in addition to needing the `!important` in the :focus and :valid rules, in order for `:valid:before` to even fire I've found that your input also needs the `required` attribute

Comment: Does not work for me, Chrome 70 - I still have this : "placeholdermm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: you have to make the date field as required to make this work.

Comment: If you want the `mm/dd/yyyy` to go away just add `width: 100` to the `:before`

Answer (score 36):

use this input attribute events

```
onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-3">
  <label for="date">Date : </label>
  <input placeholder="Your Date" class="form-control" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date">
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but you need to double-click the field to see the calendar.

Comment: This does not work in ios 14 - it pops up the keyboard instead of a date chooser, but the input turns to a date field so you do not see the text you are typing.

Comment: how did you get the double-click to go away ? @Patterson

Answer (score 15):

You can use CSS's before pseudo.

```css
.dateclass {
  width: 100%;
}

.dateclass.placeholderclass::before {
  width: 100%;
  content: attr(placeholder);
}

.dateclass.placeholderclass:hover::before {
  width: 0%;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input
  type="date"
  placeholder="Please specify a date"
  onClick="$(this).removeClass('placeholderclass')"
  class="dateclass placeholderclass">
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U2Ft5/4/)**

Comment: Like the other similar answer, doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 15):

You can do something like this:

```
<input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="js-form-control" placeholder="Enter Date">
```

Answer (score 5):

The HTML5 date input field actually does not support the attribute for placeholder. It will always be ignored by the browser, at least as per the current spec.

[As noted here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this css method in order to simulate placeholder on the input date.

The only thing that need js is to setAttribute of the value, if using React, it works out of the box.

```css
input[type="date"] {
  position: relative;
}

input[type="date"]:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

input[type="date"]:focus:before,
input[type="date"]:not([value=""]):before
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="Choose date" value="" onChange="this.setAttribute('value', this.value)" />
```

Comment: This one actually works on IOs (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), where most other options do not.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox (Windows 11). The before element is not rendered.

Answer (score 4):

The `input[type="date"]` DOMElement only takes the following value: `YYYY-MM-DD`, any other format or text with be skipped.

```js
var element = document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder]');

for (var i in element) {
  if (element[i].nodeType == 1 && element[i].nodeName == "INPUT") {

    element[i].value = element[i].getAttribute('placeholder');
    element[i].style.color = "#777";

    element[i].onfocus = function(event) {
      if (this.value == this.getAttribute('placeholder')) {
        this.value = "";
        this.style.color = "#000"
      };
    };
    element[i].onblur = function(event) {
      if (this.value == "") {
        this.value = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
        this.style.color = "#777";
      }
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="bingo" />
<input type="date" placeholder="2013-01-25" />
```

---

In this exact case, with 2 `input` elements, Pure JavaScript is ~40% ± 10% faster. With 32 `input` elements, the difference remains the same (~43% ± 10% faster for Pure JS).

Answer (score 2):

Got the most easiest hack for this problem-use this syntax in your HTML-input-tag

```
      <input type="text" id="my_element_id" placeholder="select a date" name="my_element_name" onfocus="(this.type='date')" />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add a placeholder attribute to your field with the value you want, then add this jQuery:

```
$('[placeholder]').each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
  }).focus(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == $(this).attr('placeholder')) { $(this).val(''); }
  }).blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') { $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')); }
  });
```

I've not tested it for fields that can't take placeholders but you shouldn't need to change anything in the code at all.

On another note, this code is also a great solution for browsers that don't support the placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622420/input-type-date-placeholder-on-ios), I've made it work with some ":before" pseudo-class and a small bit of javascript.
Here is the idea :

```
 #myInput:before{ content:"Date of birth"; width:100%; color:#AAA; } 
 #myInput:focus:before,
 #myInput.not_empty:before{ content:none }
```

Then in javascript, add the "not_empty" class depending on the value in the onChange and onKeyUp events.

You can even add all of this dynamically on every date fields. Check my answer on the other thread for the code.

It's not perfect but it's working well in Chrome and iOS7 webviews. Maybe it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706315/713797)

initially set the field type to text.

on focus change it to type date

Answer (score 0):

just use it :

```
    var elementDate = $('input[type="date"]');
    $.each(elementDate, (key, value) => {
        if (!$(value).val()) {
            $(value).css("color", "#777");

        }

        $(value).on("focus", function (event) {
            $(this).css("color", "#000");
        });

        $(value).on("blur", function (event) {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).css("color", "#777");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so this is what I have done:

```
$(document).on('change','#birthday',function(){
    if($('#birthday').val()!==''){
        $('#birthday').addClass('hasValue');
    }else{
        $('#birthday').removeClass('hasValue');
    }
})
```

This is to remove the placeholder when a value is given.

```
input[type="date"]:before {
  content: attr(placeholder) !important;
  color: #5C5C5C;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
input[type="date"]:focus:before,
input[type="date"].hasValue:before {
  content: "" !important;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

On focus or if .hasValue, remove the placeholder and its margin.

Answer (score -1):

Using a jQuery (sure you can achieve this with Vanilla. This make sure the date format still the same.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sdate').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'date');
  });
  $('.sdate').on('blur', function() {
    if(!$(this).val()) { // important
      $(this).attr('type', 'text');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="sdate" placeholder="From">
```

Comment: This will not be supported in all browsers

Answer (score -3):

**CSS**

```css
input[type="date"] {position: relative;}
input[type="date"]:before {
 position: absolute;left: 0px;top: 0px;
 content: "Enter DOB";
 color: #999;
 width: 100%;line-height: 32px;
}
input[type="date"]:valid:before {display: none;}
```

```html
<input type="date" required />
```