# placeholder name not displaying in html

Tags: html

Hi in the below code placeholder name was not displaying but it showing date format.But I want to display both.

Expected output:

```
Date Of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy)
```

**html**

```
<input type = "date" name="date_birth" pattern = "^\D{0,100}$" required = "required" class="login-input" placeholder="Date Of Birth" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
input[type="date"]:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #aaa;
  }
  input
[type="date"]:focus:before,
input
[type="date"]:valid:before {
    content: "";
  }
```

Via- [How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```html
<input placeholder="Date Of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy)" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')"  id="date">
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/r2njykq0/)

Note: It works on Chrome. Not Sure About other browsers.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox 36.0.4

Comment: Its not working because input type = "date" is not supported in Firefox