# Material UI can't add placeholoder to TextField type Date

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add placeholder to textfield with type="date". In normal case when type="number" || type="text" placeholder works perfect, but using type="date" It's not working anymore. Have You ever had this problem and know how to resolve it?

Comment: Nothing to do with react or material-ui directly, but in HTML5 a input of type date, does simply not have the placeholder attribute. https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#input-type-attr-summary  You can simulate it though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field)