# how to change the default placeholder of input type date HTML5

Tags: php, html, css

is there an opportunity to change the default placeholder?

[image: default placeholder]

I already tried to change the `<value="<input something>"/>` and i also tried the placeholder tag but none of them worked

maybe someone can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A html input tag is written like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="placeholder text" value="input text">
```

The placeholder text is only displayed when the value is empty.

Comment: okay that's right but how do I change the "tt.mm.jjjj" to e.g. "Enter a date"?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were asking about a date field. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field/34565565)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS like below:

```
  input[type="date"]:before {
    content: attr(placeholder) !important;
    color: #aaa;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
  }
  input[type="date"]:focus:before,
  input[type="date"]:valid:before {
    content: "";
  }
```

Then in the HTML page, do like below:

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Choose a Date" />
```

The solution is taken from this StackOverflow answer: [How do I simulate placeholder functionality on input date field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146350/how-do-i-simulate-placeholder-functionality-on-input-date-field)