# How do I use "onfocus" &. "onblur" for input type date in React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, input, onblur, onfocus

Does anyone know how to make this code work in a React Functional Component?

```
onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"
```

I am trying to get placeholder text to appear prior to the user clicking on the input element. Then when clicked, the input will change to MM/DD/YYYY.

**Trying to emulate something like this in my React project:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/34565565/14677057

Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a state variable for the type, then use it in what you render:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [type, setType] = useState('text');
  return (
    <input 
      type={type} 
      onFocus={() => setType('date')} 
      onBlur={() => setType('text')}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked! Was wondering if there was another inline way rather than using states.

Comment: If you're using react, then state is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can useRef for focusing. onBlur will work in camel case.

```
eg:
    function CustomTextInput(props) {
      // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
      const textInput = useRef(null);
      
      function handleClick() {
        textInput.current.focus();
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={textInput} />
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Focus the text input"
            onClick={handleClick}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Keerthi! Appreciate your response to this.

Answer (score 0):

Handling events with react elements is syntactically different from DOM elements.

- events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase.
- We need to pass a JSX function, rather than a string.

`

```
function HandleInputField(){
   const onChange=()=>{//your code}
   const onFocus=()=>{//your code}
   const onBlur=()=>{//your code}
   return <input onChange={} onFocus={} onBlur={}/>
 }
```

`